# Representing multiple values within one class member

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I've been working on some electrical network simulation software ([ElecNetKit](https://github.com/capnfabs/ElecNetKit)). In electrical networks, sometimes it's convenient to work with single-phase models, sometimes in three-phase models.

As such, I would like to be able to represent one of the electrical network elements as:

```
class Bus
{
    public Complex Voltage {set; get;} //single phase property
}
```

but simultaneously in a fashion so that the user can call `Bus.Voltage.Phases[x]`, and expect a `Complex` for any valid integer `x`.

The `Bus.Voltage` property should map to `Bus.Voltage.Phases[1]` when treated as a `Complex`.

I've got two questions here:

1. **Is this in violation of any OOP principles?** I've got a feeling that it might be.
2. **Is there a convenient way to represent this in C#?**

In terms of representation, I've tried:

- a class `Phased<T> : T`, but this is incompatible with the typing system, and
- a class `Phased<T>` with a generic converter to type `T`, but the converter still needs to be invoked.

I'm aware that I can simply use something like:

```
public Dictionary<int,Complex> VoltagePhases {private set; get;}
public Complex Voltage {
    set {VoltagePhases[1] = value;} 
    get {return VoltagePhases[1];}
}
```

but there's a lot of repetition once you start to do this for multiple properties, across multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would propose something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Numerics;

namespace Test
{
    class PhaseList
    {
        private Dictionary<int, Complex> mPhases = new Dictionary<int, Complex>();

        public Complex this[int pIndex]
        {
            get
            {
                Complex lRet;
                mPhases.TryGetValue(pIndex, out lRet);
                return lRet;
            }
            set
            {
                mPhases.Remove(pIndex);
                mPhases.Add(pIndex, value);
            }
        }
    }

    class PhasedType
    {
        private PhaseList mPhases = new PhaseList();
        public PhaseList Phases { get { return mPhases; } }
        public static implicit operator Complex(PhasedType pSelf)
        {
            return pSelf.Phases[1];
        }

        public static implicit operator PhasedType(Complex pValue)
        {
            PhasedType lRet = new PhasedType();
            lRet.Phases[1] = pValue;
            return lRet;
        }
    }

    class Bus
    {
        public PhasedType Voltage { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bus lBus = new Bus();

            lBus.Voltage = new Complex(1.0, 1.0);
            Complex c = lBus.Voltage;
            lBus.Voltage.Phases[1] = c;
            c = lBus.Voltage.Phases[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just be careful with implicit operators, generally they are a bad idea even though they may make your code look a bit simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something like this? This will work similar to your solution at the bottom but because of the generic class you are not repeating the code for each property.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Collection<Complex> complex = new Collection<Complex>();
        //TODO: Populate the collection with data

        Complex first = complex.First;
        Complex another = complex.Items[2];
    }
}

public class Complex
{
    // implementation
}


public class Collection<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }

    public T First
    {
        get
        {
            return (Items.Count > 0) ? Items[1] : null;
        }
        set
        {
            if(Items.Count > 0) 
                Items[1] = value;
        }
    }
}
```